# Scrapy, Crawling Reviews on Tripadvisor: extract more hotel and user information

Tags: python, scrapy

in need to extract more information from tripAdvisor

my code:

```
 item = TripadvisorItem()

item['url'] = response.url.encode('ascii', errors='ignore') 

item['state'] =  hxs.xpath('//*[@id="PAGE"]/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a/span/text()').extract()[0].encode('ascii', errors='ignore')
if(item['state']==[]):
    item['state']=hxs.xpath('//*[@id="HEADING_GROUP"]/div[2]/address/span/span/span[contains(@class,"region_title")][2]/text()').extract()

item['city'] =  hxs.select('//*[@id="PAGE"]/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[3]/a/span/text()').extract()
if(item['city']==[]):
    item['city'] =hxs.xpath('//*[@id="HEADING_GROUP"]/div[2]/address/span/span/span[1]/span/text()').extract()
if(item['city']==[]):
  item['city']=hxs.xpath('//*[@id="HEADING_GROUP"]/div[2]/address/span/span/span[3]/span/text()').extract()
item['city']= item['city'][0].encode('ascii', errors='ignore')

item['hotelName'] =  hxs.xpath('//*[@id="HEADING"]/span[2]/span/a/text()').extract()
item['hotelName']=item['hotelName'][0].encode('ascii', errors='ignore')

reviews = hxs.select('.//div[contains(@id, "review")]')
```

1. For every hotel in tripAdvisor, there is a id number for the hotel. like 80075 for this hotel: http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g60763-d80075-Reviews-Amsterdam_Court_Hotel-New_York_City_New_York.html#REVIEWS

how can i extract this id from the TA item?

2. More information i need for every hotel : shortDescription, stars, zipCode, country and coordinates(long, lat). Can i extract this things?
3. i need to extract for every review the traveller type. how?
   my code for review:

   ```
   for review in reviews:
   it = Review()

   it['state'] =  item['state']

   it['city'] =   item['city']

   it['hotelName'] = item['hotelName']

   it['date'] = review.xpath('.//div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/span[2]/@title').extract()
   if(it['date']==[]):
       it['date']=review.xpath('.//div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/span[2]/text()').extract()
   if(it['date']!=[]):
       it['date']=it['date'][0].encode('ascii', errors='ignore').replace("Reviewed","").strip()

   it['userName'] = review.xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"username mo")]/span/text()').extract()
   if (it['userName']!=[]):
           it['userName']=it['userName'][0].encode('ascii', errors='ignore')

   it['userLocation'] = ''.join(review.xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"location")]/text()').extract()).strip().encode('ascii', errors='ignore')

   it['reviewTitle'] = review.xpath('.//div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[contains(@class,"quote")]/text()').extract()
   if(it['reviewTitle']!=[]):
       it['reviewTitle']=it['reviewTitle'][0].encode('ascii', errors='ignore')
   else:
       it['reviewTitle'] = review.xpath('.//div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/a/span[contains(@class,"noQuotes")]/text()').extract()
       if(it['reviewTitle']!=[]):
           it['reviewTitle']=it['reviewTitle'][0].encode('ascii', errors='ignore')

   it['reviewContent'] = review.xpath('.//div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/p/text()').extract()
   if(it['reviewContent']!=[]):
       it['reviewContent']=it['reviewContent'][0].encode('ascii', errors='ignore').strip()

   it['generalRating'] = review.xpath('.//div/div[2]/div/div[2]/span[1]/img/@alt').extract()
   if(it['generalRating']!=[]):
       it['generalRating'] =it['generalRating'][0].encode('ascii', errors='ignore').split()[0]
   ```

there is a good manual how to find these things? i lost myself with all the spans and the divs..

thanks!

Comment: for the initial id question you can use `response.css('#SAVES span.savesHover::attr(data-locationid)').extract_first()`

Comment: ok, got it. thanks. what about the other things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it acceptable to get it from the URL using a regex?

```
id  = re.search('(-d)([0-9]+)',url).group(2)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to do this in purely XPath. Unfortunately, it looks like most of the info you want is contained in `<script>` tags:

### Hotel ID - Returns "80075"

`substring-before(normalize-space(substring-after(//script[contains(., "geoId:") and contains(., "lat")]/text(), "locId:")), ",")`

Alternatively, the Hotel ID is in the URL, as another answerer mentioned. If you're sure the format will always be the same (such as including a "d" prior to the ID), then you can use that instead.

### Rating (the one at the top) - Returns "3.5"

`//span[contains(@class, "rating_rr")]/img/@content`

There are a couple instances of ratings on this page. The main rating at the top is what I've grabbed here. I haven't tested this within Scrapy, so it's possible that it's popoulated by JavaScript and not initially loaded as part of the HTML. If that's the case, you'll need to grab it somewhere else or use something like Selenium/PhantomJS.

### Zip Code - Returns "10019"

`(//span[@property="v:postal-code"]/text())[1]`

Again, same deal as above. It's in the HTML, but you should check whether it's there upon page load.

### Country - Returns ""US""

`substring-before(substring-after(//script[contains(., "modelLocaleCountry")]/text(), "modelLocaleCountry = "), ";")`

This one comes with quotes. You can always (and you should) use a pipeline to sanitize scraped data to get it to look the way you want.

### Coordinates - Returns "40.76174" and "-73.985275", respectively

Lat: `substring-before(normalize-space(substring-after(//script[contains(., "geoId:") and contains(., "lat")]/text(), "lat:")), ",")`
Lon: `substring-before(normalize-space(substring-after(//script[contains(., "geoId:") and contains(., "lat")]/text(), "lng:")), ",")`

I'm not entirely sure where the short description exists on this page, so I didn't include that. It's possible you have to navigate elsewhere to get it. I also wasn't 100% sure what the "traveler type" meant, so I'll leave that one up to you.

As far as a manual, it's really about practice. You learn tricks and hacks for working within XPath, and Scrapy allows you to use some added features, such as regex and pipelines. I wouldn't recommend doing the whole "absolute path" XPath (i.e., `./div/div[3]/div[2]/ul/li[3]/...`), since any deviation from that within the DOM will completely ruin your scraping. If you have a lot of data to scrape, and you plan on keeping this around a while, your project will become unmanageable very quickly if any site moves around even a single `<div>`.

I'd recommend more "querying" XPaths, such as `//div[contains(@class, "foo")]//a[contains(@href, "detailID")]`. Paths like that will make sure that no matter how many elements are placed between the elements you know will be there, and even if multiple target elements are slightly different from each other, you'll be able to grab them consistently.

XPaths are a lot of trial and error. A LOT. Here are a few tools that help me out significantly:

- [XPath Helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) (Chrome extension)
- `scrapy shell <URL>`
- `scrapy view <URL>` (for rendering Scrapy's response in a browser)
- [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) (if you're interested in getting data that's been inserted via JavaScript)

Hope some of this helped.

Comment: i found the hotelid and the coordinates in simpler node: <div class="mapContainer" data-lat="40.76174" data-lng="-73.985275" data-name="Amsterdam Court Hotel" data-locid="80075" data-pinimg="http://static.tacdn.com/img2/maps/icons/pin_centroid_addressblock.png">